# PHP file_get_contents to use variables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-get-contents

I am trying to send the contents of javascript file using file_get_contents. The problem i'm having is the javascript contains some PHP variables:

```
<script>
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
    $('a.ajax_link').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/groups/$org_ID/leave/$member_ID',

            success: function(data){
                var data = $('<div>').html(data);
                var msg1 = data.find('#msg1');

                $('#data_box1').html(msg1).hide().fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
                setTimeout('window.location.href =\"/groups/\"',3000);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Specifically, the url: line. That just stays as plain text and so my script fails. I now understand this is the behavior of file_get_contents but how can I go about doing this?

thanks!

Comment: try `url: '<?php echo '/groups/'.$org_ID.'/leave/'.$member_ID;?>',
`

Comment: +1 @Death - you will also need to `include` the JS file rather than using `file_get_contents()`

Comment: The combination of both your answers solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use output buffering and `require`:

```
$org_ID = 5;
$member_ID = 10;
ob_start();
require '/path/to/javascript_file.php';
$js_code = ob_get_clean();
```

Inside javascript file you'll have to use php tags:

```
url: '<?php echo "/groups/$org_ID/leave/$member_ID"; ?>'
```